# Change system JRE from 64bit to 32bit (Windows 8 x64)

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I use some native 32bit dll libraries in my java project. While running it with Eclipse I just swich my default 64bit jre to 32bit. But when I change jre path in all keys in regedit at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->JAVASOFT->Java Runtime Environment" for my system, I get:

> Error: could not open `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is better off on [superuser](http://superuser.com) since it's not really related to programming. I'm quite sure this question is already answered there.

Comment: `But when I change jre path in all keys`, this is a bad idea. You can install additional any version. You may vary the installation path at beginning of the install process. Then run a .bat and select the appropiated version.

Comment: IOW, you can just run the 32-bit `java.exe` directly from `Program Files (x86)` rather than using the one in the Windows folder.

Answer (score -1):

I had a *the exact same error message*, and carefully moved the old java files to another folder, and then reinstalled the java runtime.  That exact same error message went away.  This is a way to solve the question asked.

Comment: If you would like to contest moderator actions on other posts, please flag the specific posts and explain. You can also raise a discussion on [meta].